# How to create filter option in RDLC report column ?

Tags: filter, report, rdlc, viewer

I wanted to have filter option (like the one available in Excel sheet) in rdlc report column. is it possible and how ?

http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/2223/sample1n.png

i am trying in Visual studio 2005 and Microsoft report viewer.

kindly let me know the option for this or a work around for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interactive sort that is available that will let you have an up/down arrow on the column to sort the column after the report is created.  It's not like the Excel filter options though.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the data from the query in the data source or you can even use the Sorting or Filters option inside the properties menu of the report to filter the data. but if you want to do this while the code is running you need to create a custom query in the data set.

something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Name WHERE CategoryTofilter = @variable
```

and then modify the table adapter string

```
int var;
this.tblName.Fill(this.DataSetName.tbl_Name, Variable)
this.reportViewerName.RefreshReport();`
```

and that should do the trick.